# Accessing firebase crash without owner credentials

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I need to get access to firebase crashes from my client Google play service account. Is it possible to get crashes without taking actual credential of account? What service are available for this? What steps to be followed if it is possible? What are the credentials I should be having for this? I heard that it is possible through Service Account.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no programmatic access to crash reports.  A service account will not help. There is only a service account used to upload your ProGuard mappings after a build.

Also, there is currently no direct link between crash reports in the Play store console and Firebase.  The Play store console will show only the reports that your users have chosen to report, when prompted at the time of a crash.  Firebase contains all exceptions that were successfully captured and sent.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible below are the steps to enable

You can give us “viewer” permission on firebase.

1. Navigate to firebase
   https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Select desire project – IPL Lumea.
3. Select ‘Setting’ at top left panel.

[image]

4. Select IAM and then add members Gmail ID and set role as “Viewer”.

[image]